# Change text in json file in python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to change the text in a JSON file that has dictionary keys that contain certain identifiers such **glucose_6_phosphote_C**. I am trying to change the **_C** part, which is found in numerous different keys such as **ID** and **reaction**. So far my code looks like this:

```
with open("reactions.json", "r") as data_file:
    data_reactions = json.load(data_file)
    for key in data_reactions:
        # strip the contents of trailing white spaces (new line)
        for data in data_reactions[key]:
            if isinstance(data_reactions[key][data], str):
                data_reactions[key][data].replace('[1]','[_e]')
                print(data_reactions[key][data])
            else:
                pass
```

How the text looks like in a file:

```
    "rxn13889": {
    "abbreviation": "PHCYTr_PA", 
    "abstract_reaction": "null", 
    "aliases": "null", 
    "code": "(1) cpd00052[0] + (0.02) cpd11422[0] <=> (1) cpd00012[0] + (0.02) cpd11427[0]", 
    "compound_ids": "cpd00012;cpd00052;cpd00067;cpd11422;cpd11427", 
    "definition": "(1) CTP[0] + (1) H+[0] + (0.02) 1,2-diacyl-sn-glycerol 3-phosphate[0] <=> (1) PPi[0] + (0.02) CDP-diacylglycerol[0]", 
    "deltag": "284.392", 
    "deltagerr": "1.95808", 
    "direction": "=", 
    "ec_numbers": "null", 
    "equation": "(1) cpd00052[0] + (1) cpd00067[0] + (0.02) cpd11422[0] <=> (1) cpd00012[0] + (0.02) cpd11427[0]", 
    "id": "rxn13889", 
    "is_obsolete": 0, 
    "is_transport": 0, 
    "linked_reaction": "null", 
    "name": "phosphatidate cytidylyltransferase reversible", 
    "notes": "null", 
    "pathways": "null", 
    "reversibility": "<", 
    "status": "MI:C:-8.82/H:-12.78/N:-2.94/O:-6.86/P:-0.98|CI:-1.02", 
    "stoichiometry": "-1:cpd00052:0:0:\"CTP\";-1:cpd00067:0:0:\"H+\";-0.02:cpd11422:0:0:\"1,2-diacyl-sn-glycerol 3-phosphate\";1:cpd00012:0:0:\"PPi\";0.02:cpd11427:0:0:\"CDP-diacylglycerol\""
},
```